# Dollar sign in URL in Texmaker

Tags: symbols, texmaker, urls

I am trying to format a URL using the `url` package. My URL has a dollar sign ($) in it.

This line

```
\url{\\000.000.000.00\ Redirected$ \DBLocker}
```

compiles correctly and the result is what I want.

However, the text editor in `Texmaker` highlights everything after the dollar sign (until the end of the document!) in **green** (eg. math mode format) which is obviously very annoying .

I can't just add another dollar somewhere to close math mode as it isn't actually open, so the `.tex` file wouldn't compile!

It's as if `Texmaker` doesn't appreciate that $ signs are not escaped in URLs.

Things I have tried:

1. **Escaping the dollar sign with a backslash.**  This doesn't work as the backslash shows in the URL.
2. **Using** `\textbackslash` **and similar.** Also doesn't work, they appear as literal strings in the URL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try to add an $ after a comment sign: %$

Comment: Can't TeXmaker use filters for highlighting?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you see in Texmaker? Also, you shouldn't have to jump through hoops and modify your source code just to obviate shortcomings of your TeX IDE. File this as a bug in the [Texmaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list).

Comment: This is also seen in other editors. Ulrikes solution is usually the fastest

Comment: Now sorted thanks @Jubobs. I will file a bug report.

Comment: Yes. I think this is not uncommon - and not restricted to this case. (It happens with other cases where editors don't parse the syntax fully.) I'm guessing that they use a relatively simple algorithm to decide e.g. what is maths. (But why Kile can't match curly brackets properly is truly beyond me - all it needs to do is *count*!)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I suggest you make your comment an answer - I can't find a good duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could  add an `$` after a comment sign: `%$`